# RDLC always showing first record in all columns

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new to reports and was using RDLC as they have an option of client side processing.

I was using web site datasource as objectdatasoruce and assigning List to the report.

Though I see my List has all 3 employees records, but when I run the report I see always first employee information 3 times. I'm using table control and employee data is span accross different rows in the table. it has 3 rows and 5 columns and all three rows I was using was detail row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press right click of your mouse on text boxes that exist in your data table. see the expression window of text box. maybe there is a `First` expression before your expression. if it exist please delete that.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the key in your model is unique. If not, create a composite key to make the rows unique.